# Printing to console in C++ when a new window is created or focus is shifted using Hooks

Tags: c++, windows, hook

Trying to do some operation when the contents of the monitor (any windows appearing / created / destroyed), so for now, trying to print a message to the console when:

- A new window appears on the screen
- Current window is closed
- Application is switched

Tried using `Hooks`, which I think is the right way to go. I referred to: https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c-/83707-setwindowshookex-example.html

Also referred to Windows Website for info on hooks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw

Edit: Every time this code runs, I get the error "Failed to install Hook" I have tried running this on vsc console, regular console, and as admin, same result everytime

```cpp
/* variable to store the HANDLE to the hook. Don't declare it anywhere else then globally
 or you will get problems since every function uses this variable. */
HHOOK _hook;

// This struct contains the data received by the hook callback. As you see in the callback function
// it contains the thing you will need: vkCode = virtual key code.
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct; // This is currently useless will need to remove this

/** 
 * This is the callback function. Consider it the event that is raised when, in this case,  a key is pressed.
 */
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

        std::cout << "Hook Triggered - Code:" << nCode << ", wParam: " << wParam << ", lParam: " << lParam << std::endl;

        // Somecode here to detect change in window and above mentioned stuff
        // Print change if the above event occured.
        ReleaseHook();

 
    // call the next hook in the hook chain. This is necessary or your hook chain will break and the hook stops
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook(){
    // Set the hook and set it to use the callback function above
    // WH_KEYBOARD_LL means it will set a low level keyboard hook. More information about it at MSDN.
    // The last 2 parameters are NULL, 0 because the callback function is in the same thread and window as the
    // function that sets and releases the hook. If you create a hack you will not need the callback function 
    // in another place then your own code file anyway. Read more about it at MSDN.
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, HookCallback, NULL, 0))){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to install hook!", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        std::cout << "Unable Hook!";
    } else{
        std::cout << "Hooked!";
    }


}

void ReleaseHook(){
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the WH_CALLWNDPROC hook to monitor window creation, destruction, and switching. The following code shows how to do this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (nCode) {
    case HC_ACTION: {
      HWND hWnd = (HWND)wParam;
      if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND) {
        cout << "Window created: " << hWnd << endl;
      } else if (nCode == HCBT_DESTROYWND) {
        cout << "Window destroyed: " << hWnd << endl;
      } else if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE) {
        cout << "Window activated: " << hWnd << endl;
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
      return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, HookCallback, NULL, 0);
  if (hHook == NULL) {
    cout << "Failed to install hook!" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
  return 0;
}
```

This code will print a message to the console whenever a window is created, destroyed, or activated. You can modify the code to do whatever you want when these events occur.

Comment: I got Failed to install hook. Is there a critical bit that I am missing? I am using g++ version 4.x on Windows 10.